# delete everything in a many-to-many relationship (JPA)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, many-to-many

I have the following model (reduced):

```
@Entity
public class Video {
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "video_tag", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "video_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private Set<Tag> tags;
}

@Entity
public class Tag {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Video> videos;
}
```

I have a database where videos are connected to multiple tags and vice versa. I want to delete all videos and cascade it to delete all tags as well. Calling remove on a Video entity results in a cycle and after a few round of going back and forth between a tag and a video, the java compiler prints a stack dump of the cycle.

How can I remove a video / all videos using *JPA*, preferably by removing all videos and cascading the remove to the tags.

Comment: Do you want to remove *a* video, or all videos and all tags? This is completely different. You can't delete the tags of a video when deleting the video, since the tagx might be referenced by other videos. Cascading the delete of a ManyToXxx association makes no sense. If the goal is to remove everything from the three tables, I would just 3 SQL queries.

Comment: I want to delete everything (all tags and all videos) in the database using JPA

Comment: Then I'd just use 3 SQL queries: `delete from video_tag; delete from video; delete from tag;`

Comment: Looks like you are looking for repoObj.deleteAllInBatch();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actions are:

1. Breakdown relationships (object schema)
2. Update owner entity (video in this case)
3. Remove videos entities also remove tag entities because cascade anotation in Video Class.

   ```
   //Remove relationships
   List<Video> videoList;
   for (Video v : videoList) {
       for(Tag t : video.getTags()){
           t.getVideos.remove(v);
           v.getTags.remove(t);
       }
   }

   //Update owner entities
   for (Video v : videoList) {
       Session sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
       Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
       sess.update(v);
       tx.commit();
       sess.close();
   }

   //Remove owner entities
   for (Video v : videoList) {
       Session sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
       Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
       sess.delete(v);
       tx.commit();
       sess.close();
   }
   ```